# How to "filter" a tail output throug awk and grep?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, tail

On a special console I like to filter some informations from /var/log/syslog. That was not really tricky:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | awk '{print $2,$1,$9,$3,"\033[1;36m"$17 "\033[0m","\033[1;33m"$23 "\033[0m","\033[1;36m"$19 "\033[0m","\033[1;33m"$24 "\033[0m","\033[1;38m"$26"\033[0m","\033[1;32m"$13"\033[0m","\033[1;31m"$20 "\033[0m";}'
```

But now I want to pipe this through grep for a special field. Just adding a "| grep Fieldname" does not work, even not grep first, awk later (which would make more sense).

Could you please give me a tip?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use `grep`, do the pattern match in `awk`.

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | awk '/Fieldname/ {print $2,$1,$9,$3,"\033[1;36m"$17 "\033[0m","\033[1;33m"$23 "\033[0m","\033[1;36m"$19 "\033[0m","\033[1;33m"$24 "\033[0m","\033[1;38m"$26"\033[0m","\033[1;32m"$13"\033[0m","\033[1;31m"$20 "\033[0m";}'
```

If you really need to use `grep`, you can use the `--line-buffered` option so it doesn't buffer the output.

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep --line-buffered Fieldname | awk '{print $2,$1,$9,$3,"\033[1;36m"$17 "\033[0m","\033[1;33m"$23 "\033[0m","\033[1;36m"$19 "\033[0m","\033[1;33m"$24 "\033[0m","\033[1;38m"$26"\033[0m","\033[1;32m"$13"\033[0m","\033[1;31m"$20 "\033[0m";}'
```

If you want to `grep` the output of `awk`, you should use `fflush()` after printing each line to flush the buffer immediately.

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | awk '{print $2,$1,$9,$3,"\033[1;36m"$17 "\033[0m","\033[1;33m"$23 "\033[0m","\033[1;36m"$19 "\033[0m","\033[1;33m"$24 "\033[0m","\033[1;38m"$26"\033[0m","\033[1;32m"$13"\033[0m","\033[1;31m"$20 "\033[0m"; fflush();}' | grep Fieldname
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, the '/Fieldname/' is exactly what I need. Thank you very much! :-)